# Writing Query result to .ttl file format

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

Any ideas on how to save the results of this SPARQL query into a TURTLE format?

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select distinct ?city ?labelEn{
?city a dbo:City.
?city rdfs:label ?labelEn.
filter(lang(?labelEn) = 'en').
}
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense for a tuple, right? How would the RDF triple look like given that you have only `?city ?labelEn` as result? If you want proper triples, use `CONSTRUCT`: `PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
construct {
?city rdfs:label ?labelEn.
} where {

{ select distinct ?city ?labelEn{
?city a dbo:City.
?city rdfs:label ?labelEn.
filter(lang(?labelEn) = 'en')
}
LIMIT 10
}}`

Comment: The `SELECT` query is not necessary, if you don't want to have a limit on the size of the results:`PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
construct {
?city rdfs:label ?labelEn.
} where {
?city a dbo:City.
?city rdfs:label ?labelEn.
filter(lang(?labelEn) = 'en')
}`

Comment: In that case, the default limit of DBpedia will return only 10000 triples though

Comment: Thanks a million, I have what I was looking for.

Comment: So how can I modify the query to get results like this `dbr:Berlin rdf:type dbo:City.
dbr:Berlin rdf:label „Berlin“.`

Comment: Thanks for the helo

Comment: In that case, you have to add the triple to the first part of the `CONSTRUCT`: `PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> construct { ?city a dbo:City . ?city rdfs:label ?labelEn. } where { ?city a dbo:City. ?city rdfs:label ?labelEn. filter(lang(?labelEn) = 'en') }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to just [ask the DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20%3Fcity%20%3FlabelEn%7B%0D%0A%3Fcity%20a%20dbo%3ACity.%0D%0A%3Fcity%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FlabelEn.%0D%0Afilter%28lang%28%3FlabelEn%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2010&format=text%2Fturtle&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) to do so. Of course, you may not be expecting the reification that [results there](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20%3Fcity%20%3FlabelEn%7B%0D%0A%3Fcity%20a%20dbo%3ACity.%0D%0A%3Fcity%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FlabelEn.%0D%0Afilter%28lang%28%3FlabelEn%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2010&format=text%2Fturtle&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20).

Later comments suggest what you really want is rather different from your original question...  More like --

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

CONSTRUCT
 { ?city           a  dbo:City . 
   ?city  rdfs:label  ?labelEn . 
 } 
WHERE
 { ?city a dbo:City . 
   ?city rdfs:label ?labelEn . 
   FILTER(lang(?labelEn) = 'en') 
 }
```

-- which again you can [ask the endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20%20rdfs%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20dbr%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0ACONSTRUCT%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fcity%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20%20dbo%3ACity%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%3FlabelEn%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fcity%20a%20dbo%3ACity%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FlabelEn%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28lang%28%3FlabelEn%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2010&format=text%2Fturtle&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) to [serialize as Turtle](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20%20rdfs%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20dbr%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0ACONSTRUCT%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fcity%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20%20dbo%3ACity%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%3FlabelEn%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fcity%20a%20dbo%3ACity%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FlabelEn%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28lang%28%3FlabelEn%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2010&format=text%2Fturtle&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20).

Comment: Can I specify in the query how the endpoint needs to serialize the query?

Comment: @FrankMensah - When querying against Virtuoso, you can add [the `DEFINE output:format` pragma](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlimplementatioptragmas/#rdfsparqlimplementatioptragmasctr) to the start of your SPARQL query.  For Turtle output, `DEFINE output:format "TTL"` or `DEFINE output:format "TURTLE"`.